# WORDPRESS: Create a function which updates database on click

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a function but I have come to a hurdle, I want to make the if/else hrefs clickable and I need them to add/remove entries into the database, whats the best way to do this?

```
    // FAVORITE
function favorite($user_id, $post_id) {

    // DB Connection
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "???", "???", "???");

    // Check Favorite
    $getFavoriteQuery = "
        SELECT  *
        FROM    wp_favorites
        WHERE   user_id = $user_id
        AND     post_id = $post_id";

    $favoriteQuery = $mysqli->query($getFavoriteQuery); 

    if (mysqli_num_rows($favoriteQuery)) { ?>

        <a href="#">Un-favorite</a>

        <!-- UPDATE DATABASE MYSQLI QUERY -->

    <?php } else { ?>

        <a href="#">Favorite</a>

        <!-- UPDATE DATABASE MYSQLI QUERY -->

    <?php }

}
?>
```

Comment: Use GET parameters, then check for them in the code. Example: `http://somedomain.com/wordpress/?action=unfavourite&user=someuser`. In PHP you'll get the `$_GET` global array populated with `action` and `user` indexes. `$action = $_GET['action']; // $action == 'unfavourite'`. From then on, you can attach your logic behind each action. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way necessarily, it certainly isn't the cleanest but it should give you an idea of which direction to head in. Also this is (I think) pretty much what @[iSS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3631997/iss) meant. So credit.

Front End

```
function isUserFavorite($user_id, $post_id) {

    // DB Connection
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "???", "???", "???");

    // Check Favorite
    $getFavoriteQuery = "
        SELECT  *
        FROM    wp_favorites
        WHERE   user_id = $user_id
        AND     post_id = $post_id";

    $favoriteQuery = $mysqli->query($getFavoriteQuery); 

    if (mysqli_num_rows($favoriteQuery))
        return true
    else 
        return false
}

if(isUserFavorite($user, $post)){
    $url = "http://domain.com/some/page/with/processing.php?action=unfavorite&user=$user&post=$post";
    $link = "UnFavorite";
}
else{
    $url = "http://domain.com/some/page/with/processing.php?action=favorite&user=$user&post=$post";
    $link = "Favorite";

<a href="<?php echo $url"><?php echo $link ?></a>
```

Processing.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action'],$_GET['user'],$_GET['post']){
    //MySQL Connect

    if($_GET['action']=='favorite'){
        //Query to favorite
    } 
    else if ($_GET['action']=='unfavorite'){
        //Query to unfavorite
    }
    //Redirect here if you like
}
else
    echo "Missing parameter"
```